# How do I include classes in a buildfile for ant?

Tags: java, ant

I am creating a jar file of a javaagent that I have written. However, that agent depends on another java library.

So, I would like to know, how do I include a whole package that is being used by my program into the jar file so that it can be used when the jar gets executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unzip the jar you want to include and put it the final jar.  Here are the ant commands that will do this for you.

```
<target name="package">
  <!-- Staging  is simply a temporary directory for exploding the jar files.  You
       can call the directory whatever you want.  -->
  <property  name="staging.dir" location="staging"/>

  <mkdir  dir="${staging.dir}"/>

  <unjar dest="${staging.dir}">
    <fileset dir="lib" >
      <include name="*"/>
    </fileset>
  </unjar>

  <mkdir dir="classes"/>

    <javac debug="on" srcdir="src" destdir="classes" target="1.5" includes="**/*">
        <classpath refid="build.class.path"/>
    </javac>


     <jar destfile="Product.jar"
          basedir="classes"
          excludes="**/Test.class">
       <fileset  dir="${staging.dir}"/>
     </jar>

    <!-- Delete the temporary staging directory.  -->
    <delete dir="${staging.dir}" />
</target>
```

Comment: hey thanks. i am just getting confused with the variables u used and to what locations they point to? Can you tell me a little about that. Sorry for inconvinience. I am total newbiew to ant and could not find any good tutorial on google :(

Comment: Edited with comments to explain the staging variable.